# I want to add a image on python but cant

Tags: python

Ok I have tried almost everything and well im angry and cant figure it out I have tried opening the file but it couldn’t open it because open was undefined then I changed the file name from jpeg to gif even though its not a gif but it loaded but not with the image this is the code I got off google but still wasn’t successful and dont now what have I done wrong and why wont the image appear I have the image in my files I was thinking it was because i am useing replit but mabye im wrong here’s my code currently

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter

root = Tk()

image = Image.open('Trash.gif')
image = image.resize((20, 20))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
canv.grid(row=2, column=3)

img = PhotoImage(file=image)

root.mainloop()
```

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated last time I asked for help it really was helpful so thats why I'm reaching out to the community thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image needs to go inside a `Label`.

You also only need to construct the image once.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter

root = Tk()

image = Image.open('Trash.jpg')
image = image.resize((20, 20))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
canv.grid(row=2, column=3)

label = Label(root, image=image)  # Image needs to go inside a label
label.grid(row=3, column=2)       

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was trying to add it into a label but i gave up and tried other things you dont now how happy this makes me thanks so much for taking your time to help me out i really do appreciate it :)

Comment: How would you add this in a def not to be needy but it’s not working

Comment: I did but I want to make it into a event a so I can make a key bind and it wasn’t working

Comment: can you post the code that isn't working? @BassetHoundDevelopment

Comment: I can’t find it but it’s just the code up above combined  i will try to find it and post it when I get back from school